# Redefine Arduino library constants

Tags: arduino

I would like to redefine a library constant ('SERIAL_BUFFER_SIZE', in my case) for my Arduino Due (SAM board architecture). I did so in 'RingBuffer.h, but the problem is that once the library updated through the Arduino update mechanism, my change reverted to the default value. Is there a best practices way to change library constants?